# Jquery tabs, how to redirect?

Tags: php, jquery

Hello all you programmers, well I have one problem with jQuery tabs. I am using jQuery for navigation between tabs, and jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("ul.vertical-tab li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$(".tab-content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

//On Click Event
$("ul.vertical-tab li").click(function() {
    $("ul.vertical-tab li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $(".tab-content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
    return false;
});

});
```

First tab is always default, so when I work on second tab, and submit data to external php script, redirection always returns me on the first(default tab). 
My redirection looks like this:***header('Location:http://www.administrator.php');***

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO student (firstname,lastname) VALUES('$firstname','$lastname')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
header('Location:http://www.administrator.php');
mysqli_close($con);
```

So because I use jQuery I can't redirect myself to desired tab using address. Help :/

Comment: I'd worry more about the [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) holes you've got in your code. Plugging those is a far bigger priority than some glitchy tabs.

Comment: oh, i'm not worried by the security, cause I am writing this project for college course, so I just want to work...

Comment: College course or not, you would be well-advised to make it a habit to worry about security.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a hash-based lookup such as:

`link: http://www.administrator.php/#secondtab`

```
$firsttab = window.location.hash ? 
    $(window.location.hash) : 
    $("ul.vertical-tab li:first");
$.firsttab.addClass('active').show();
```

Then you just need Ids for your tabs to match (eg `id="secondtab"`)

Comment: i'm confused where i should write this second part of code? somwhere inside this jquery code, as a independent function??

Comment: replace `$("ul.vertical-tab li:first").addClass("active").show();` with it. It will at least get you started